# Creating Autocomplete hint for multiline textfield widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Autocomplete widget shows a list below the text field. My Autocomplete text field is also multiline using fieldViewBuilder that may cover the whole page. I want hints show up near the cursor. Just like the [Autocomplete (Widget of the Week)](https://youtu.be/-Nny8kzW380?t=10) video has teased.

Comment: I don't think `Autocomplete` widget has this feature yet. I suggest you to look into https://pub.dev/packages/super_editor, there might be a way to achieve what you want using it